# Emacs linum border to wide

Tags: emacs

My linum margin is wide (about 6 characters). In most examples on the web, it's not. How can this be changed?

There are no specific parameters set by myself. I am using emacs mac port. There is a custom theme, but it does set anything.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`linum-format` controls the formatting.  If you `(setq linum-format 'dynamic)` it should adapt the width on the fly.  If you want to hardcode the number of columns, you could do, say, `(setq linum-format "%5d")` for a 5-column number.

Comment: To get this working in init.el I had to do: `(add-hook 'linum-before-numbering-hook '(lambda () (setq linum-format "%4d ")))`